How can I give a standard macOS account admin-like privileges while restricting system reset and specific app access on the latest macOS?
I’m using the latest macOS (Sonoma, as of December 2024), and I’ve set up a standard account for myself while a trusted friend holds the admin account credentials.
I want my standard account to have the ability to:

Install macOS updates (e.g., security patches, new macOS versions).
Update apps downloaded from the Mac App Store and external sources.
Manage DNS settings, profiles, and perform general system tasks.

However, I also need to restrict the following capabilities:

Factory resetting or erasing the Mac.
Access to specific apps (e.g., Apple Configurator or System Preferences).

I’ve considered:

Using sudo to grant specific permissions to the standard account.
Locking sensitive settings and apps with profiles or Screen Time.
Automatic updates for macOS and apps.

What’s the best way to configure the standard account to have admin-like privileges for updates and general system management, but still prevent it from resetting the Mac or accessing restricted apps?

The short answer is you don't without a lot of work. Are you doing this for many machines to investing in MDM or custom software configuration toolsets like "Santa" makes sense? Also, what does "considered" mean for sudo, and screen time? It's not at all clear what you are trying to prevent, since you list all the things an admin does with admin permissions.

Have you looked at Privileges?
https://github.com/SAP/macOS-enterprise-privileges

"General System tasks" and installing updates are admin tasks. I think we'd be able to you the best solution if you explained the setup a bit more, and what you're trying to achieve. Is this your Mac, or someone else's? Are you likely to reset the Mac, or access those apps if allowed to do so?

I'm going to make an assumption, which may be wrong, about what you're trying to achieve. I assume that, like me, you don't want to do anything with admin privileges that doesn't require those privileges.
I have two user accounts on my Macs: one admin (which I hardly use), and one standard, in which I do all my work. I can switch between them with Fast User Switching, but I usually don't have to.
I've set up Touch ID and for both accounts, using different fingers, and SSH access for root (public-key authentication only). When I'm logged in to both accounts and working in the standard account, I can escalate privileges using SSH in the shell, and using Touch ID in (most) GUI apps, or by entering the admin password when necessary.
As for System Settings, some of them (such as WiFi network selection) can optionally be made accessible to a standard user without privilege escalation.
Now, if you're trying to make it actually impossible for yourself to do some admin tasks, this approach won't work, but in that case, there's something more that needs to be understood about your requirements.

The accounts are for two different people. One person has full admin access, the other can use a few specific admin applications.
